# ln: failed to create symbolic link : permission denied

Tags: bash

Every time I open terminal it shows like this "ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/www/html': Permission denied" How can I remove this message?

Answer (score 2):

This likely means `ln` is called in your user or bash profile to create a symbolic link in a folder that requires root permissions. Try running `nano ~/.profile` and `nano ~/.bash_profile` (`nano` can be replaced if you prefer a different command line text editor). You then just need to search for a line saying `ln <some other file> /var/www/html` and comment it out.

Some other files you can check if it is not in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` are:

- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.bashrc`

**Edit:**
If you feel it may be important to keep it, but only want to remove the error message you can instead add `2> /dev/null` to the end of the command.

```sh
# Before
ln <some other file> /var/www/html

# Ignore standard error output, but still run command
ln <some other file> /var/www/html 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: how to  run that with sudo?